# Spree: How to add a new controller under spree admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have been trying to add a new controller under spree admin, but having a tough time figuring it out.

The new controller is VerificationDocumentsController

My code is as below,

```
module Spree
    module Admin
      class VerificationDocumentsController < Spree::Admin::ResourceController
        def index
        end

      end
    end
end
```

My routes is,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end


Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do 
   namespace :admin do
     resources :verification_documents
   end
end
```

but when I am trying to hit the url

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/verification_documents
```

its showing me the error

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/verification_documents"
```

Dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What your rake routes says?

Answer (score 0):

This works in V3.2.0.RC2:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
    namespace :admin, path: Spree.admin_path do
      resources :verification_documents
    end
  end
```